# Get day name based on custome ID of bigint[] datatype

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to display Day name based on ID which is in bigint[] in the table as shown below:

Table:

```
create table tbl_days
(
day_ids bigint[]
);
```

Records:

```
insert into tbl_days values('{1,2}');
insert into tbl_days values('{1,2,3}');
insert into tbl_days values('{1,4}');
insert into tbl_days values('{4,7}');
insert into tbl_days values('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}');
insert into tbl_days values('{2,4,7}');
```

Would like to display day name for:

1 for Monday
2 for Tuesday
.
..
7 for Sunday.

Query 1: Using `replace()`, which is taking 3 more seconds to get the main query result.

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(day_ids::varchar,'1','Monday'),'2','Tuesday'),'3','Wednesday'),'4','Thursday'),'5','Friday'),'6','Saturday'),'7','Sunday') 
from tbl_days;
```

Query 2: Using `string_agg()`, here problem with an order.

Step 1: Add days into temp table

```
create temp table temp_days
(
id int,
days varchar
);

insert into temp_days values(1,'Monday'),(2,'Tuesday'),(3,'Wednesday'),(4,'Thursday'),(5,'Friday'),(6,'Saturday'),(7,'Sunday');
```

Step 2: Join with main table

```
select d.day_ids,string_agg(distinct t.days,',') 
from tbl_days d 
inner join temp_days t on t.id = any(d.day_ids)
group by d.day_ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2a02aef034bc5d2cef282427a3848fd5)

```
SELECT
    id,
    string_agg(                                               -- 4
        CASE day                                              -- 3
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
        END,
        ','
        ORDER BY index_in_array                               -- 4
    ) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER () as id                            -- 1
    FROM tbl_days
) s,
unnest(day_ids) WITH ORDINALITY as t(day, index_in_array)     -- 2
GROUP BY id
```

1. For my approach you need an `id` column. This creates one. If you already have one, you can ignore this step
2. `unnest()` expands the array into one row per element. The `WITH ORDINALITY` clause adds an `index` to the records which saves the position of the element in the original array
3. Replace the numbers with the related string using a `CASE` clause
4. Reaggregate the weekdays by their original `id`s. The order can be ensured by using the in (2) created `index`, which can be using in the `ORDER BY` clause of the aggregate